# Open Graph : Java Script : active access token must be used to query information about the current user

Tags: php, javascript, facebook-opengraph

Can any one tell me what is wrong with below code of open graph call.

i have tried with app token , user token and with out any token every time its response me with

{"error":{"message":"An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.","type":"OAuthException","code":2500}}

i have verified app token , user token and my code with fb debugger

```
<?php
$appId = '****************';
$appSecret = '*************************';
$appNameSpace = 'og_loctest';

$token_url =    "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?" .
        "client_id=" . $appId .
        "&client_secret=" . $appSecret .
        "&grant_type=client_credentials";
$response = file_get_contents($token_url);

$params = null;
parse_str($response, $params);
$access_token = $params['access_token'];
?>

<html xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml" lang="en">
<head prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns# fb: http://ogp.me/ns/fb# og_loctest: http://ogp.me/ns/fb/og_loctest#">
  <meta property="fb:app_id" content="<?php echo $appId;?>" /> 
  <meta property="og:type"   content="og_loctest:properties" /> 
  <meta property="og:url"    content="http://nirav-metronew.kwetoo.com/fbtest/" /> 
  <meta property="og:title"  content="Sample Properties" /> 
  <meta property="og:image"  content="https://s-static.ak.fbcdn.net/images/devsite/attachment_blank.png" />
  <title>OG Tutorial App</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="fb-root"></div>
  <script>
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
      FB.init({
        appId      : "<?php echo $appId;?>",
        status: true,
        cookie: true,
        xfbml: true,
        frictionlessRequests: true,
        useCachedDialogs: true,
        oauth: true
      });
    };

    // Load the SDK Asynchronously
    (function(d){
      var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
      js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
      js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
      d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
    }(document));

    function fblogin()
    {
         FB.login(function(response) {
           if (response.authResponse) {
             postProperties();
           }
         },{scope: 'email,offline_access,publish_stream,publish_actions'});
    }

      function postProperties()
      {

          FB.api(
            '/me/og_loctest:post',
            'post',
            { properties: 'http://nirav-metronew.kwetoo.com/fbtest/',access_token:"<?php echo $access_token;?>"},
            function(response) {
               if (!response || response.error) {
                  alert('Error occured');
               } else {
                  alert('Facebook open graph tested! Action ID: ' + response.id);
               }
            });
      }  
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <form>
    <input type="button" value="Post properties" onclick="fblogin()" />
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

> Can any one tell me what is wrong with below code of open graph call.

Your script logic is flawed – because you confused what’s happening client- and what server-side, and *when*.

```
      FB.api(
        '/me/og_loctest:post',
        'post',
        { properties: 'http://nirav-metronew.kwetoo.com/fbtest/',
          access_token:"<?php echo $access_token;?>"},
```

You are calling this client-side, in the callback of FB.login. If the user just logged in, then PHP, *which has already run earlier on your server* has no way of knowing the current access token which just resulted in the client-side login. PHP can’t look into the future … so whatever is put out in this place in the end, it will definitively not be the current access token that you think it is.

But the JS SDK is perfectly capable of handling it’s access token itself, so you don’t have to explicitly pass it as a parameter into this API call – just take the part `access_token:"…"` out completely.

Comment: Thanks for answering my que ..
yes you are right man but i am passing application access_token and as i think application access token does not depends on users session 

By the way i have tried what you have mentioned and i got this response of my fb call.
{"error":{"message":"(#15) This method must be called with an app access_token.","type":"OAuthException","code":15}}

Comment: You can’t access the Graph API using `/me/…` when using an application access token, because then the API has no way of knowing who “me” is supposed to be. Make your call to `/userid/…` instead.